# MemcacheServiceFactory class not found error after deploying to Google app engine (Java)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, memcached

Everything works fine on local system but after deploying to Google App Engine, it throws the following error about Memcache. Is this because of any recent changes to GAE sdk?

```
com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyLogger warn: Error for /api/utilities (JettyLogger.java:29)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/api/memcache/MemcacheServiceFactory
    at DataRetriever.getUtilitiesListJson(DataRetriever.java:29)
```

Comment: I'm seeing this general problem after upgrading from 1.9.76 to 1.9.77.  The SDK jar is *not* set to "provided", and it *does* appear in WEB-INF/lib.  I haven't been able to fix it yet.

Comment: I had same issue ... the problem was a miss-match of gcloud vs. plain GAE SDK tools -- gcloud had some old components (versions). It worked when I used old-school "mvn appengine:update".

Answer (score 1):

I found a related post [Adam response](https://grokbase.com/t/gg/google-appengine/15cyyc4mmz/memcacheservicefactory-class-not-when-using-memcache-features-on-my-appengine-instance).

This might help you:

"It sounds like you are missing the necessary App Engine JARs in your WEB-INF/lib directory in the WAR package that is being deployed.

If you are using the Google Plugin for Eclipse [link](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/appengine) I'd recommend creating a new Web Application project and try re-deploying, after ensuring that WEB-INF/lib contains the App Engine JARs.

If you are using Apache Maven [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven) try creating a new project from the appengine-skeleton-archetype to ensure the necessary dependencies are specified in your pom.xml."

Comment: Thanks Marian. The only thing that worked for me was to downgrade the appengine-api-1.0-sdk from 1.9.77 to 1.9.34. Probably something got changed in latest version. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Trying to upgrade from 1.9.76 to 1.9.77 then I started seeing this error

Answer (score 0):

The issue is a disconnect between the new API jar version 1.9.77 and an old tooling stack.
To update your tooling stack, make sure you have the latest GAE SDK Maven/Gradle plugins version, or Cloud SDK plugin version, as well as the latest Cloud SDK itself.
For example, you need to run

gcloud components update

so that gcloud -version can show a java GAE version of 1.9.77 or above.
But updating all tools (Plugins, SDKs, or IDE integrations) depending on what you use, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

My issue wasn't after deploying to app engine, just running locally. I needed these dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
        <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.80</version>
    </dependency>
```